# What's a plugin to record video and audio in HTML5 with fallback to Flash?

Tags: html, flash, plugins

The plugin can be open source or paid. It just needs to be a stable, trustworthy solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found https://github.com/f5io/fifer-js for audio. For video, try this: https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js. Of course, you can go through the code and modify it to allow audio recording too. using getUserMedia() seems easy, I have no idea about flash though. I haven't tested either of those, intend to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this http://mediaelementjs.com/ Not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that! It's great for playing back video/audio, I'm actually looking for something to record video/audio in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There's no HTNL5 video format and HTML5 cannot record any video.